# How do I execute npm install and npm from Jenkins if my project is in not in the root directory

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm

Lets say I have in private repository directory called project. So I want either copy what inside this folder to Jenkins workspace or copy all repository but run npm install(npm run) from Workspace/project/.

How do I execute npm install and npm from Jenkins if my project is in not in the root directory --prefix path doesn't work

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "not in the Root" directory?

Comment: Lets say I have in private repository directory called project. So I want either copy what inside this folder to Jenkins workspace or copy all repository but run npm install(npm run) from Workspace/project/.

Comment: If I understand your requirement correctly. Do you want to checkout a private repository and execute npm from within the `project` directory if that directory exists? If the directory doesn't exist what do you want to do? Are you using declarative pipelines?

Comment: I know this directory exists, So after Jenkins sync with github I want to run npm from Jenkins Workspace/project/. No pipelines.

Comment: How are you executing `npm`?

Comment: Without Jenkins - npm run wdio

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple pipeline code for you to build on top of.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                // Clone your repo
                git 'https://github.com/jglick/simple-maven-project-with-tests.git'
            }
        }
        stage('NPM Run') {
            steps {
                // dir will execute you commands within this directory. Another option is to cd in to the project directory and execute your command.  
                dir('project') {
                    sh "npm run wdio" 
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And how I do it using windows script commands? Strange bud cd doesn't work.

Comment: Instead of `sh` use `bat`. `bat "npm run"`. Refer to this for more information https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#bat-windows-batch-script

Comment: It worked only when I started external bat file, but only 1 npm command.

Comment: If you want to execute multiple commands use three quotes. `bat """" command """"`